# how to navigate to a new page on clicking an item in the listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

I am building an app in windows phone 7 where i need to navigate to a new page on clicking an item in the listbox.

My xaml code is:

```
<ListBox Name="listBox1" SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged"  Height="676" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
```

My cs file for navigation is

```
 private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       // If selected index is -1 (no selection) do nothing
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
        return;

        // Navigate to the new page
         NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/NewsDetails.xaml?selectedItem=" + listBox1.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));

        // Reset selected index to -1 (no selection)
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

I want to navigate to NewsDetails page. But here when i click an item in the listbox nothing happens. Can anyone please help me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Is `listBox1_SelectionChanged` called? If no, make sure that there are no `Button`'s or other controls that grabs touch events in `ListBoxItem`